# Finding mismatched item for same index in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have following lists

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','a']
l2 = ['a','d','c','c']
```

I want to find out elements from l2 which do not match to elements of l1 at the same index.
eg: output for above list would be ['d','c']

as l2 should have 'b' at 2nd position.

I can do this by iterating over the list and finding the mismatch.

```
l3 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] != l2[i]: l3.append(l2[i])
print l3
```

Is there any better way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
missing = [b for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue=object()) if a != b]
```

is a little more pythonic ... but basically the same thing

Comment: I think using `izip_longest` here is misleading, because it only solves half of a problem (that the OP doesn't have). What if `l1` is longer than `l2`, but its extra values are all `None`? In some applications that might be the right behavior. In others, you can solve that by using `fillvalue=object()`. But just suggesting `izip_longest` as better than `zip` without even mentioning it seems like it's going to lead people to trouble.

Comment: yeah I agree @abarnert... thanks for mentioning it ... :) any fillvalue could exist in the the comparison list, and that is certainly a shortcoming ... but it would take more lines to really handle that case right ... so I simplified it to this, even though there are certainly edge cases that would break it

Comment: @JoranBeasley: If you write `fillvalue=object()`, that is a brand-new value that can't already exist in the list, and can't even _equal_ anything in the list unless someone goes out of their way to be malicious or stupid. So it doesn't take any more lines to handle that case right. (And having `None` in a list is not that rare of an edge case; that's why so many functions in the stdlib do the `sentinel = object()` thing.)

Comment: thanks @abarnert goes to show I still have plenty to learn... I had never really thought of using that as a sentinal ... in the past I have created a new class that just always returns false on eq

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I've used a never-equal class for something where I needed `!=` even when `is`, but I can't remember what. Maybe a `cmp_to_key`-type function?

Answer (score 3):

Python list comprehension, without needing to import any modules like itertools.

```
l3 = [b for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if b != a]
```

Whenever you find yourself wanting to do a for loop wherein at each iteration you may be appending to something that started as an empty list, think of using a list comprehension.

Comment: except it will not return the right results if they are not the same size ... but yeah +1 ... I almost wrote this answer but decided to use itertools.izip_longest because I knew someone would come along and leave a comment just like this one ;P

Comment: I upvoted your comment, but then I just tested the case where they are not the same size (tried it lopsided in both directions), and it seemed to work (using Python 2.7.7). Or, I should say, it did not add the trailing items from the longer list.  Maybe that is not the correct/desired result.  Actually, I'm going to about face again and say yours is probably the better answer since it would stick on those trailing things from the longer list.  :p

Comment: yeah I agree it is not clear what OP desires in the case the lists are not the same size ... either answer could be correct ... I just usually error on the side of caution and give more info rather than lose information

Answer (score -1):

If you have the same size lists you can use `enumerate`:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','a']
l2 = ['a','d','c','c']
print [ele for ind,ele in enumerate(l2) if ele != l1[ind]]
['d', 'c']
```